# Linking closely related topics

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What's best practice here, just to post a cf. comment on the original post with a list of older and newer questions that are strongly related, so all of the questions show up in the "linked" menu? Or should I be considering adding tags to questions that might not have them, instead? Or perhaps a feature, like the ability to manually add to the "related" list, is more appropriate.

For instance, I just answered [question A](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/do-immortal-organisms-exist), which is linked to [question B](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/why-is-the-hydra-biologically-immortal?lq=1) and [question C](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/is-there-any-kind-of-immortality-in-plants?lq=1) but shares no tags with them. Question B is related to [question D](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/difference-in-telomeres-between-a-thale-cress-plant-and-a-methuselah-tree?rq=1) (but not A or C), is only linked back to A, and shares one tag with B and two with D. Question C is linked to [Question E](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/do-trees-age-on-a-microscopic-level?lq=1), but not related to any of the others here although it shares one tag with B, C, and D. I won't finish this exercise in one-way streets, but the point is that I found myself going down the garden path a bit.

Ideally, it seems like if one goal is curation of a permanent knowledge base, questions that are so similar should be very obviously connected.

Then again, I suppose the fundamental nature of SE is a specific questioner receiving an answer to a specific question. Thoughts?

Comment: A unifying tag of "aging" (synonym for "senescence") could probably be added to all of them.

Comment: The "Linked Questions" sidebar widget is imperfect, but it's unlikely to get an update any time soon. (It's way low on the list of priorities.) In the meantime, links in comments are a good way to get links to show up there if you feel like they should be there. A comment pointing out related discussions or questions is rarely out of place.

Comment: Thanks, that's two answers: **tags** and **comment links** that seem like good solutions.